# Does Windows 7 support Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v

Does Windows 7 support running Hyper-V Manager?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It already does.
You can get the RSAT tools from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en)

They include the Hyper-V manager for Windows 7.

After installing the above download, go to  Windows Features in Control Panel and choose the 'Role Administration Tools'.  Select Hyper-V Tools from there.

Edit: Link updated to current version.

Comment: +1 because your the only one who actually answered the question correctly :)

Comment: Finally, a link to the download!!

Comment: You might also want to be aware that although Windows 7 can manage Hyper-V on 2008, it can't manage all of the features of Hyper-V 2012, including the free hypervisor product.

Comment: Now that link is removed my Microsoft , Try this link[https://thesystemcenterblog.files.wordpress.com/2021/02/9ec67-rsat-tools-for-windows-7-64-bit.zip]

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 cannot host Hyper-V. There is a new version of [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) that you can use on it.

The [Remote Administration](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f6c62797-791c-48e3-b754-c7c0a09f32f3&displaylang=en) tools can be downloaded here. It includes Hyper-V manager but must be enabled in the Windows Feature activation in the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial [Manage Hyper-V remotely from windows 7](http://devonenote.com/2010/04/manage-hyper-v-remotely-from-windows-7/), worked for me