# SCVMM Installation Requirements for a Hyper-V Environment

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, system-center, scvmm

I have 3 hosts (+1 for management with windows 7) and I would like to implement virtualisation on the Hyper-V platform. I downloaded Hyper-V Server 2008 R2.

Can the SCVMM be installed on windows 7 host? Does it have any other requirements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Windows 7 support Hyper-V Manager?](http://serverfault.com/questions/31285/does-windows-7-support-hyper-v-manager)

Comment: no, it relates to Hyper-V manager. I was asking about System Center, Virtual Machine Manager. What does it offer more over in fact?

Comment: SCVMM Server needs to be installed on Windows Server (will not install on Hyper-V Server). The SCVMM Admin Console (for working with SCVMM) will install on Win7. SCVMM needs an SQL server (express works); if you use the SSP it needs IIS. SCVMM can integrate with SCOM if you have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCVMM adds quite a few things over the basic Hyper-V manager app.  You get things such as a storage library, so that you can create templates of VMs.  Then rapidly deploy them out to your hosts.  You get a very nice online P2V migration utility.  You also get some batch management capabilities, such as being able to evacuate all VMs from a single host with a minimal set of clicks.  The list goes on.

Microsoft Documentation:

http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/virtual-machine-manager.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If by "virtual machine manager" you mean the Hyper-V Manager *console*, yes, it can be installed on Windows 7 (see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/31285/does-windows-7-support-hyper-v-manager)).

If you are instead referring to Microsoft's [System Center Virtual Machine Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/virtual-machine-manager.aspx), the centralized management system for Hyper-V hosts, then no, it will only run on Windows Server 2008 R2; but its *management console* will happily run on Windows 7.

You can find the complete system requirements [here](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/virtual-machine-manager/vmm-system-requirements-r2.aspx).